# No highestCommittedUSN attribute found for AD root - How to configure the (admin) User?

Tags: ldap, confluence

The problem feels THAT basic, that I couldn't find an answer - I feel stupid - whatever ...

"Hand-crafted" LDAP-Directory to connect to ...

---

**Setup (probaply not needed):**
Connecting Atlassian-Confluence to a LDAP Directory

The connection itself works (Host, Password etc.)
[Pic - generally works](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/pca05u6k5thjuej/AAD_entfW4jx_wHC3Ko9ZW6_a?dl=0&preview=Connect%26Sync_Fail.png)

As it can be seen, the synchronisation does not work.
(as 'first' in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f3XWlXfl97s) ~3:08 min)

Another Confluence-Page sais: Look into the 'Confluence Logs'

[Pic - failed connection](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/pca05u6k5thjuej/AAD_entfW4jx_wHC3Ko9ZW6_a?dl=0&preview=Connection%26Sync.png)

In the LOGs it says:

> 2020-06-15 10:03:18,099 INFO [Caesium-1-1] [agent.service.check.StaleChecksCleaner] info Cleaning stale checks
>   2020-06-15 10:03:40,676 INFO [http-nio-8090-exec-4] [embedded.admin.list.DirectoriesController] sync User directory synchronisation requested: [ Active-Directory-Server ], type: [ CONNECTOR ]
>   2020-06-15 10:03:40,720 INFO [Caesium-1-1] [atlassian.crowd.directory.DbCachingRemoteDirectory] synchroniseCache INCREMENTAL synchronisation for directory [ 294914 ] starting
>   2020-06-15 10:03:40,722 INFO [Caesium-1-1] [atlassian.crowd.directory.DbCachingRemoteDirectory] synchroniseCache Attempting INCREMENTAL synchronisation for directory [ 294914 ]
>   2020-06-15 10:03:40,723 INFO [Caesium-1-1] [directory.ldap.cache.UsnChangedCacheRefresher] synchroniseChanges After restarting, full sync of directory [294914] is necessary before incremental sync is possible.
>   2020-06-15 10:03:40,723 INFO [Caesium-1-1] [atlassian.crowd.directory.DbCachingRemoteDirectory] synchroniseCache Incremental synchronisation for directory [ 294914 ] was not completed, falling back to a full synchronisation
>   2020-06-15 10:03:40,723 INFO [Caesium-1-1] [atlassian.crowd.directory.DbCachingRemoteDirectory] synchroniseCache INCREMENTAL synchronisation for directory [ 294914 ] was not successful, attempting FULL
>   2020-06-15 10:03:40,765 INFO [Caesium-1-1] [atlassian.crowd.directory.DbCachingRemoteDirectory] synchroniseCache failed synchronisation complete for directory [ 294914 ] in [ 45ms ]
>   2020-06-15 10:03:40,773 INFO [CrowdUsnChangedCacheRefresher:thread-2] [directory.ldap.cache.UsnChangedCacheRefresher] call found [ 0 ] remote groups in [ 48ms ]
>   2020-06-15 10:03:40,781 ERROR [Caesium-1-1] [atlassian.crowd.directory.DbCachingDirectoryPoller] pollChanges Error occurred while refreshing the cache for directory [ 294914 ].
>   com.atlassian.crowd.exception.OperationFailedException: No highestCommittedUSN attribute found for AD root
>       at com.atlassian.crowd.directory.MicrosoftActiveDirectory.fetchHighestCommittedUSN(MicrosoftActiveDirectory.java:700)
>       at com.atlassian.crowd.directory.ldap.cache.UsnChangedCacheRefresher.synchroniseAll(UsnChangedCacheRefresher.java:148)
>       at com.atlassian.crowd.directory.DbCachingRemoteDirectory.synchroniseCache(DbCachingRemoteDirectory.java:978)
>       at com.atlassian.crowd.manager.directory.DirectorySynchroniserImpl.synchronise(DirectorySynchroniserImpl.java:67)
>       at com.atlassian.crowd.directory.DbCachingDirectoryPoller.pollChanges(DbCachingDirectoryPoller.java:45)
>       at com.atlassian.crowd.manager.directory.monitor.poller.DirectoryPollerJobRunner.runJob(DirectoryPollerJobRunner.java:85)
>       at com.atlassian.confluence.impl.schedule.caesium.JobRunnerWrapper.doRunJob(JobRunnerWrapper.java:117)
>       at com.atlassian.confluence.impl.schedule.caesium.JobRunnerWrapper.lambda$runJob$0(JobRunnerWrapper.java:87)
>       at com.atlassian.confluence.impl.vcache.VCacheRequestContextManager.doInRequestContextInternal(VCacheRequestContextManager.java:84)
>       at com.atlassian.confluence.impl.vcache.VCacheRequestContextManager.doInRequestContext(VCacheRequestContextManager.java:68)
>       at com.atlassian.confluence.impl.schedule.caesium.JobRunnerWrapper.runJob(JobRunnerWrapper.java:87)
>       at com.atlassian.scheduler.core.JobLauncher.runJob(JobLauncher.java:134)
>       at com.atlassian.scheduler.core.JobLauncher.launchAndBuildResponse(JobLauncher.java:106)
>       at com.atlassian.scheduler.core.JobLauncher.launch(JobLauncher.java:90)
>       at com.atlassian.scheduler.caesium.impl.CaesiumSchedulerService.launchJob(CaesiumSchedulerService.java:435)
>       at com.atlassian.scheduler.caesium.impl.CaesiumSchedulerService.executeLocalJob(CaesiumSchedulerService.java:402)
>       at com.atlassian.scheduler.caesium.impl.CaesiumSchedulerService.executeQueuedJob(CaesiumSchedulerService.java:380)
>       at com.atlassian.scheduler.caesium.impl.SchedulerQueueWorker.executeJob(SchedulerQueueWorker.java:66)
>       at com.atlassian.scheduler.caesium.impl.SchedulerQueueWorker.executeNextJob(SchedulerQueueWorker.java:60)
>       at com.atlassian.scheduler.caesium.impl.SchedulerQueueWorker.run(SchedulerQueueWorker.java:35)
>       at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
>   2020-06-15 10:03:40,785 INFO [CrowdUsnChangedCacheRefresher:thread-1] [directory.ldap.cache.UsnChangedCacheRefresher] call found [ 0 ] remote users in [ 61ms ]

---

**Actual problem:**

To fulfill the "No highestCommittedUSN attribute found for AD root"-Warning, I live in the assumption that I need a 'cn' in a specific folder.

Example LDAP-Directory:
picture[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wafi.png)

[Pic - Example LDAP-Directory](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/pca05u6k5thjuej/AAD_entfW4jx_wHC3Ko9ZW6_a?dl=0&preview=LDAP_Directory.png)

Some Admin-Accounts were created (equal, except the cn), but none is working.

LDAP-Scheme for lookup and Basis-DN (Confluence lookup Information):
[Pic - LDAP-Scheme](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/pca05u6k5thjuej/AAD_entfW4jx_wHC3Ko9ZW6_a?dl=0&preview=LDAP_Scheme.png)

If i get the oreilly-openbook right, the user shall be a 'cn' as in [here](https://www.oreilly.de/german/freebooks/linag3ger/nag17de.html#195524)

```
dn: cn=JaneAdmin,o=vbrew
objectClass: organizationalRole
cn: JaneAdmin
description: Linux System Admin Guru
```

---

**Finally:**

Do I use 'the wrong Tag' (e.g.: 'cn') on the User?

Is there a flaw in the LDAP-Scheme lookup?

Does the "admin"-user need to be in another specific folder?

What else could be wrong?

---

Thanks already for reading    :D

Answer (score 0):

Finally it worked with the following sample data (no personal information in there).
The following ldif data can e.g. be imported via **Apache Directory Studio** into the LDAP-Directory.

Save the data via any text editor with   **.ldif**   ending.

```
version: 1

dn: dc=testdir,dc=net
objectClass: domain
objectClass: top
dc: testdir

dn: ou=appOne,dc=testdir,dc=net
objectClass: groupOfUniqueNames
objectClass: top
cn: appOne
uniqueMember: uid=p0009,ou=users,dc=testdir,dc=net
ou: appOne

dn: ou=appOne-Edit,ou=appOne,dc=testdir,dc=net
objectClass: groupOfUniqueNames
objectClass: top
cn: appOne-Edit
uniqueMember: uid=p0009,ou=users,dc=testdir,dc=net
ou: appOne-Edit

dn: ou=appOne-Lead,ou=appOne,dc=testdir,dc=net
objectClass: groupOfUniqueNames
objectClass: top
cn: appOne-Lead
uniqueMember: uid=p0009,ou=users,dc=testdir,dc=net
ou: appOne-Lead

dn: ou=appOne-Read,ou=appOne,dc=testdir,dc=net
objectClass: groupOfUniqueNames
objectClass: top
cn: appOne-Read
uniqueMember: uid=p0009,ou=users,dc=testdir,dc=net
ou: appOne-Read

dn: ou=appTwo,dc=testdir,dc=net
objectClass: groupOfUniqueNames
objectClass: top
cn: appTwo
uniqueMember: uid=p0009,ou=users,dc=testdir,dc=net
ou: appTwo

dn: ou=appTwo-Edit,ou=appTwo,dc=testdir,dc=net
objectClass: groupOfUniqueNames
objectClass: top
cn: appTwo-Edit
uniqueMember: uid=p0009,ou=users,dc=testdir,dc=net
ou: appTwo-Edit

dn: ou=appTwo-Lead,ou=appTwo,dc=testdir,dc=net
objectClass: groupOfUniqueNames
objectClass: top
cn: appTwo-Lead
uniqueMember: uid=p0009,ou=users,dc=testdir,dc=net
ou: appTwo-Lead

dn: ou=appTwo-Read,ou=appTwo,dc=testdir,dc=net
objectClass: groupOfUniqueNames
objectClass: top
cn: appTwo-Read
uniqueMember: uid=p0009,ou=users,dc=testdir,dc=net
uniqueMember: uid=p1115,ou=users,dc=testdir,dc=net
ou: appTwo-Read

dn: ou=roles,dc=testdir,dc=net
objectClass: organizationalUnit
objectClass: top
ou: roles

dn: ou=users,dc=testdir,dc=net
objectClass: organizationalUnit
objectClass: top
ou: users

dn: uid=p1110,ou=users,dc=testdir,dc=net
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person
objectClass: top
cn: p1110
sn: Maribel Speed
uid: p1110
userPassword:: p1110

dn: uid=p1111,ou=users,dc=testdir,dc=net
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person
objectClass: top
cn: p1111
sn: Bryce Holt
uid: p1111
userPassword:: p1111

dn: uid=p1112,ou=users,dc=testdir,dc=net
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person
objectClass: top
cn: p1112
sn: Wade Whitmore
uid: p1112
userPassword:: p1112

dn: uid=p1113,ou=users,dc=testdir,dc=net
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person
objectClass: top
cn: p1113
sn: Darlene Shepherd
uid: p1113
userPassword:: p1113

dn: uid=p1114,ou=users,dc=testdir,dc=net
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person
objectClass: top
cn: p1114
sn: Andrew Dixon
uid: p1114
userPassword:: p1114

dn: uid=p1115,ou=users,dc=testdir,dc=net
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person
objectClass: top
cn: p1115
sn: Summer Pond
uid: p1115
userPassword:: p1115

dn: uid=p0009,ou=users,dc=testdir,dc=net
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: organizationalPerson
cn: admin
sn: super
uid: p0009
userPassword:: admin
```

Have fun    ;-)